# Cannot Seem to get php.ini to Work - AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I can't seem to get the Google App Engine to recognize my `php.ini` custom file as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini).

I'm getting the error (within the logs of my app) where `php_sapi_name()` is disabled for security reasons by Google. However, it also states it can re-enabled with `google_app_engine.enable_functions`.

So my `php.ini` looks like this:

```
;enables function disabled by Google
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, php_uname"
```

Yet even after I add and upload the `php.ini` file, it shows the same error for newer requests. I did also browse my code through the App Engine dashboard to check to see whether the `php.ini` file was updated, and it was.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yep, version mismatch is definitely a possibility here.

Comment: Yep. 100% was version mismatch. Did not know that I needed to manually switch versions, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you upload, there is a chance that this creates a new Application version for your specific app.

If it does this, you won't see the change, because the default version won't change, so you're still hitting the old version, even if the console shows you the most recent one.

Going to your console, under "Compute Engine -> App Engine -> Versions" you can see, manage, and change your default version.